# variable may not have been initialized when test

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to understand why I get "variable may not have been initialized" when I test (variable === "some text") but I dont get when I used (typeof passwordHashOrg !== 'undefined')

The working code:

```
checkPass('share', function (error, response) {
    "use strict";
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
});

function checkPass(username, callback) {
    "use strict";

    // Require
    var fs = require('fs');

    // Static Parameters
    var usernameInput = username;

    // Open shadow file
    fs.readFile('/etc/shadow', function (error, file) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error); // file does not exit
        }
        // file is a buffer, convert to string and then to array
        var shadowArray = file.toString().split('\n');

        var passwordHashOrg;
        shadowArray.forEach(function (line) {
            var shadowLineArray = line.split(":");
            var usernameOrg = shadowLineArray[0];
            if (usernameOrg === usernameInput) {
                passwordHashOrg = shadowLineArray[1];
            }
        });
        if (typeof passwordHashOrg !== 'undefined') {
            callback(null, 'userExist');
        } else {
            callback(null, 'unknownUser');
        }

    });
}
```

and the code that I get "variable may not have been initialized" :

```
checkPass('share', function (error, response) {
    "use strict";
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
});

function checkPass(username, callback) {
    "use strict";

    // Require
    var fs = require('fs');

    // Static Parameters
    var usernameInput = username;

    // Open shadow file
    fs.readFile('/etc/shadow', function (error, file) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error); // file does not exit
        }
        // file is a buffer, convert to string and then to array
        var shadowArray = file.toString().split('\n');

        var passwordHashOrg;
        shadowArray.forEach(function (line) {
            var shadowLineArray = line.split(":");
            var usernameOrg = shadowLineArray[0];
            if (usernameOrg === usernameInput) {
                passwordHashOrg = shadowLineArray[1];
            }
        });
        if (passwordHashOrg === 'some text') {
            callback(null, 'userExist');
        } else {
            callback(null, 'unknownUser');
        }

    });
}
```

The only diferent from the two code is:

**if (typeof passwordHashOrg !== 'undefined') {**

vs
**if (passwordHashOrg === "some text") {**

Comment: Seems to me that you don't have to initialize a variable in order to compare its type. Perhaps an uninitialized variable's type is already 'undefined'?

Comment: Is this a jslint or jshint warning? Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: The problem is: I'm trying to look for a specific user in a linux shadow file and if that user exist do something.
The question is: why do I get 'unknownUser' when I try to test if variable 'passwordHashOrg' have some value but if I test for defined it success.

Comment: @AdrianGherasim: Maybe because the shadow file is unlikely to contain "`some text`"?

Answer (score 4):

The warning means just what it says - the variable might not have been initialised with a value at the time of the comparison. Since that's the expected behaviour, and basically just what you want to test for, the warning can be safely ignored. Alternatively, use

```
var passwordHashOrg = null; // or
var passwordHashOrg = undefined; // or whatever default value you want
```

So why didn't you get the warning when using `typeof`? Because that's not necessarily evaluating the value of the variable, and might be seen by jshlint as justified on non-initialised variables (it even works on undeclared variables). You'd probably get the same warning if you did compare the value to `undefined`.

Comment: If I (passwordHashOrg === undefined) I dont get any warning but the code dont work.

Comment: Then probably it depends on the type of the compared-against value as well - it warns you that an uninitialised variable would fail the type check of `===` against a string literal.

Comment: Yes but why? I realy dont understand,

Comment: The both if test are after the forEach so why both dont success?

Comment: Point is: you shouldn't care. You seem to know that the variable is either still `undefined` or contains a string, and you should test for what you want to do.

Comment: They don't both land in the success case because they do different things!

Comment: I know that but from what I understand is that the (passwordHashOrg === undefined) is executing before the forEach

Comment: No, it's not. Array `forEach` is not asynchronous.

Comment: By the way, how do you know if something is asynchronous or synchronous? for exemple  Array forEach ?

Comment: Big Thanks. I already find and read that post in the meantime